# 4-20 mA current loop with a 3.3 V microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, operational-amplifier, adc, current-measurement, 4-20ma

I have an analog pressure sensor that I am trying to read. The sensor is powered by 24 V and outputs a 4-20 mA signal. I want to connect it to an ADC pin of a 3.3 V micro.

There are two designs I'm trying to understand and modify:

1)
[image: First schematic, from blog linked below]

from https://elprofezurco.blogspot.com/2021/10/construye-tu-conversor-0-20ma-to-0-10v.html

2)

[image: Second schematic, from the page linked below]

from https://electrojoan.com/interface-bucle-de-corriente-4-20ma/

Both designs are powered by 12 V:

a) Would it work without modification if powered by 5 V instead of 12 V?

b) Could it be powered by 24 V (my sensor is 24 V) and use a resistor divider at the output for the 3.3 V micro?

Comment: It all comes down to ground loops. If your measurement circuit is galvanically isolated from earth and battery powered there's a good chance you just need the 250 ohm resistor and a couple of other components.

Comment: I’m with Andy. A resistor is all that is needed. Of course some protection devices wouldn’t go astray. No need for op-amp or other shenanigans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)
**Circuit** 1 seems to have a gain of 5 on secondary amplifier stage, so 20 mA input would result in 10 V output, so 5 volts is not not enough. If you bypass the secondary stage, then the gain will be 0.1 V/mA and the circuit will work.

**Circuit 2** with a 250 ohm resistor will have an output of 0.25 V/mA, which brings the voltage up to 5 volts at 20 mA, which is then buffered without any gain by the op amp.
Top avoid loosing the top range, (due to the op amp being unable to reach output voltage close to supply) RX should be reduced to 100 ohms.
If you are using a microcontroller to read the voltage anyway, the chances are that there is no need for buffering. So with a 3.3 V microcontroller (depending on the ADC specs) you could use the 100 ohm resistor without a buffer amp, as long as you can be sure to be able to protect the MCU pins in case the return conductor is cut. I say 100 ohms as RX, even if it could be slightly higher, as the signal return conductor resistance will raise the voltage level.

b)
Resistor divider is not a good solution, even if you got it to work with certain configuration. You can use a switching mode regulator in stead (CUI Inc VXO7803-500 for example). A linear would do, but with such big voltage drop it's unnecessary generation of heat.

Comment: Great explanation @Ralph , if I understood you correctly I could use the circuit 1, powered by 5v if I modify R6, R11 and R8 and remove D2, so I will get 2 v aprox at 20 mA and protect the MCU pin from voltage over 5V

Comment: In the second circuit, if you operate the opamp at 5V, you need to lower the value of resistor RX so the output voltage of the opamp is within the output voltage swing specifications. The OnSemi data sheet shows \$V_{OH}\$ = 3.3V when using a 5V power supply, hence, the maximum value of RX is 165 ohms to prevent opamp output clipping. You may want to lower RX to match the ADC input range as Ralph suggested. Circuit #1 is an unnecessary complication since you don't need the additional gain.

Comment: Remove R11, R6, you can short R8. And yes, short D2 for circuit protection and place a similar resistor + protective device in the receiving end. If you want to keep the buffering at all. To my experience a 100 ohm resistor in 4-20 mA signal is quite common and most MCU built-in ADCs have far bigger input impedance than that.

Answer (score 1):

The *Compliance Voltage* for 4-20 mA controllers is usually either 24 V or 36 V.  Depending on the device and its power requirements you might find that most can now work on 12 V. Also depends upon the resistance of the wiring to your device - for your sensor to work requires the total resistance of the wiring to be less than ~ V/I = 3.3 V / 20 mA = 165 \$\Omega\$

What Voltage Do I Need to Operate My 4...20 mA Transducer?
https://web.archive.org/web/20160306132123/http://celesco.com/faq/420.htm

Comment: Yes I know, what I want to avoid is using another 12v supply on my pcb, If I can use the 5v already available or the 24v powering the sensor would be perfect